# How to automatically include routes in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Let's say you always wanted to do certain prefixes on routes, such as `/before` and to pop that off after a certain line in your `server.js` file.

Here's an example

```
const express = require('express');
const App = express(); 

App.get('/before') //so here the route is '/before'

App.push('/after') //This is a made up method, but something like this has to exist...

App.get('/before') //And this route would be '/after/before'

App.pop(); //Another made up method

App.get('/before') //and this would be just "/before"
```

Comment: Use a router.  Put a set of your routes on a router and then you can register that router with one parent path such as `app.use("/before", myRouter);`.  That's how you do something like this in the Express architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly the `.push()` and `.pop()` design, but it lets you accomplish the same goal of grouping routes under a common parent path without having to specific the common parent path on each route definition.

Express has the concept of a separate router.  You define a bunch of routes that want to share a common parent path on a router.  You then register each leaf path on the router and then register the whole router on the parent path.

Here's an example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const routerA  = express.Router();

// define routes on the router
routerA.get("/somePath1", ...);
routerA.get("/somePath2", ...);
routerA.get("/somePath3", ...);

// hook the router into the server at a particular path
app.use("/parentPath", routerA);

app.listen(80);
```

This registers three routes:

```
/parentPath/somePath1    
/parentPath/somePath2    
/parentPath/somePath3
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems applicable to my current project and helps me understand express overall. Thank you!